# git pre-commit hook doesn't work as expected (or it's me)

Tags: git

I have a pre-commit which is really simple :

```
[xavier@imladris python-requests]$ cat .git/hooks/pre-commit
rm -f BUILDLOCK
```

This does not work as the name suggests : the file is removed from local repository, but remains on distant, which makes my local repo marked as dirty after the commit.

Did I misunderstood the doc ? In this case, which is the proper hook to accomplish what I need, ie removing the Lock file, the commit the modifs, as well as the removal of the file

Thanks, regards,

Xavier

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pre-commit hook changed files to be added to commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503312/pre-commit-hook-changed-files-to-be-added-to-commit)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to not only remove the file, but also commit the removal?

Then don't use use `rm`, but `git rm` instead.

```
git rm -f BUILDLOCK
```

Comment: Note: You probably want to add the file to `.gitignore` so that it won't be added again in future.

Answer (score 1):

After we run `git commit` and before it's done, `pre-commit` is invoked. The result of `pre-commit` determines if `git commit` is to be done or aborted.

In your question, you mention that removing BUILDLOCK results in a dirty repository. `pre-commit` works as expected. But it's not proper to commit BUILDLOCK in the first place. Instead, it's suggested to add it in `.gitignore`. It seems that it's used as a lock file indicating that the build process is running, right? If so, the build process is responsible to create and remove it.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the quick answers.

It works now with this content

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f BUILDLOCK
git rm --ignore-unmatch -q BUILDLOCK
```

Cheers,

Xavier

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to have a pre-commit hook attempt to modify what will be committed. In particular, this attempt won't work correctly when using `git commit --only`. Pre-commit hooks should *verify that the implied commit is correct* and if so, exit zero (allow commit to proceed). If not, the pre-commit hook should print an error message and exit nonzero, forcing the user to fix the commit. Anything else is asking for future problems.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).